# Can someone explain this code // wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Can someone explain this code found in wordpress

```
$filter_name = "plugin_action_links_" . plugin_basename( __FILE__ );
add_filter( $filter_name, 'wpplugin_add_settings_link' );
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the
[ask] link for more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Can you add more information? Seem wpplugin_add_settings_link is not a default filter hook of wordpress

Answer (score 1):

`$filter_name` is a variable that is being assigned a string which begins with "plugin_action_links_" followed by the name of the plugin ([plugin_basename()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/plugin_basename/)).

The [add_filter()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/) function hooks a function called `wpplugin_add_settings_link` to the filter with a name equal to `$filter_name`.